# tirar a margin da fonte do google

Tags: css

Tem algum jeito de tirar essa `margin-top` da fonte do google? Eu sei que tem uma propriedade que afasta ou aproxima a fonte `letter-spacing`, mas não é isso que eu preciso, eu só queria tirar essa `margin` da fonte, se possível sem usar `margin` negativa, alguém sabe como?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenta `line-height: 10px`.

Pode ser necessário usar px para o tamanho da fonte.